# Android Studio Database Inspector always showing database as "closed"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, database-inspector

I am trying to use Database Inspector in Android Studio. Why I run the app on the device, it inspector is always showing my application database (highlighted in the image) as "closed".

Is there any fix for this or did I miss something during the setup?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database is a good alternative for database inspector

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UPD. last time I had this annoying issue `Invalidate cache/Restart` fixed this for me. *Sigh*

Running the app in Debug mode [image] (Win: Shift+F9 or Mac: Control+D) does the magic for me sometimes.

Not sure if this is a bug or not. [The android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database) doesn't mention on this, so I guess it should just work in normal mode, but for some reason doesn't for me..

I use (Android Studio 4.2 beta 3). Property `minSdkVersion` set to 27.

I don't use Room or any other ORM, just a few plain simplest queries.

The toggle 'Keep database connection open' doesn't seem helping either.

In normal mode:

[image]

In Debug mode (what I want):

[image]

Noticeable, that it continuing to work (querying the database etc) even after I stopped the app running in Debug mode:

[image]

Comment: I tried the above mentioned steps but didn't work. I clear the app cache and data and restarted the app and it started working.

Comment: interesting, in my case the problem was that the database was too large (15+ gb), once i cleared it - this inspection feature started working as expected

Comment: Invalidating cache + restart + app uninstall = didn't work. But probably helped doing simple select on DB before connecting 'App inspection'. Not sure ;]

Comment: `Invalidate cache/Restart` worked for me

Answer (score 19):

I was having same issue, i tried lot's of thing but didn't work and finally a day after i come to know the issue.
Issue was that i was using encrypted SQLite database (Custom ***openHelperFactory***).

For me it was the issue after removing ***openHelperFactory***

It works perfectly fine, My answer might not be not useful for you but it would be useful for someone for sure.

Thank you

Comment: Related issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153684328

Comment: is there still no support with this openHelperFactory?

Answer (score 16):

1. Click on your close database icon
2. Enable (keep open) => [image]
3. Do some action related to the database(for example get a list of ...)
4. The database stays in open mode

Answer (score 6):

For me the reason for "closed" was - most probably - that the framework I use (Exposed/SQLDroid) closes the database connection when it is not working.

So, even when everything worked fine in the application, the database was closed at the time the Database Inspector wanted to look into it.

Adding the line below basically solved the problem. I wouldn't put this into production code as I haven't checked what happens in details, but it helped during development.

```kotlin
val db = openOrCreateDatabase("testdb.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null)
// db.close() -- DO NOT USE THIS
```

Important thing is not to use `db.close()`. When `db.close()` is there, Database Inspector shows the db as closed. When it is not there, Database Inspector usually works.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I'm using SQLite database.
I've just comment this line :

`//yourDatabaseName.close();`

Then run again and hope it works.

Don't forget to uncomment the line after you finish.

Answer (score 3):

None of the posted solutions worked for me until I ran the app with a debugger instance attached then terminated the app right after the app loads on the emulator.

After that, navigating to the Database Inspector view shows the necessary data:
[image]

Comment: I was going to answer this when I saw it last in the list. Got my up vote.

Answer (score 2):

Enable "keep database connection open". See the image below

[image: Database View]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a database is autoclosed and needs to force-open the database.

```
if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                TheDatabase.class,
                DATABASE_NAME
        )
                .addCallback(callback)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }
    instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< FORCE OPEN
    return instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but there is a chance you have selected the wrong emulator/device for database inspector.
[image]

You can change the emulator for your database inspector by clicking on the name of the emulator as shown in the image.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Drift flutter database, changing the openConnection function to the code below fixed the issue for me:

```
LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder, 'db.sqlite'));

    if(Platform.isAndroid){
      return SqfliteQueryExecutor.inDatabaseFolder(path: 'db.sqlite');
    }else {
      return NativeDatabase(file);
    }
  });
}
```

Note that you will need to import sqflite in your pubspec.yaml

I found the solution in an Issue from the official github repo:
https://github.com/simolus3/drift/discussions/1818

Answer (score 1):

Weird but this is what worked for me:

1. I killed the app (what was running under Android Studio's debugger).
2. That immediately prompted a security warning dialog box which asked whether I confirm downloading the database from the smartphone to Android Studio. I clicked 'Yes'.
3. Restarting the app (via debugger) found the database closed again.
4. But killing the app again, magically displayed the app's .db as open, along with its tables.

I believe this is what's called "Offline mode" in https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database#offline-mode

I don't have an explanation for this yet but this is what worked for me on Android Studio 2021.3 (against an Android 13 target).

Answer (score 1):

The correct reason would be, You might be closing DB after insertion of data.
Just do not close the DB and check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer, but here are some other possible approaches:

From your screenshot, I see you've done this already, but for others... it sounds like [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database?utm_source=android-studio#keep-dbs-open) is how you're supposed to be able to make this work -

> Additionally, you can prevent database connections from closing by
> toggling Keep database connections open from off () to on () at the
> top of the Databases pane.

... but that didn't work for me, so I end up going to the Device File Explorer, saving the database I'm interested in to my desktop, and working with it there.

I've also had good luck with this tool:
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Room version (currently `2.2.6`) did the trick for me, but there's no mention to any such a bug in the release notes. I suspect it may have something to do with caches so maybe that's also worth trying

Answer (score 0):

Actually Debug mode does not work for me.

It worked initially. And suddenly after some successful build, again that issue came. So what I do is stop inspection and open the page where you actually query the db and then attach from app inspection, it shows DB open all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For me answer was that when you initialize(!!!!) your DatabaseHelper (or whatever it's called in your programm) Multiple times it shows database is closed, even if u dont use any of initialized variables. It may be obvious but i'm new to Android(i'm still a student) and u just might have let it unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using *Room* for the database. I have 2 activities, **MainActivity** & **DetailActivity**. The activity that is using the database operation is **DetailActivity**

> The database is not closed (open) when I opened the App Inspection when I'm
> opening **DetailActivity**, which contains the database operation

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i stopped the inspector, and the reselect the device, it started working. Hope it helps somobedy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just keep the app open and press `Stop  Inspectors` in the devices list then select the new process for inspection,
the database will be open.

Comment: Works on my machine!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I see the same issue when I didn't open co-routine with any DAO operations in the `MainActivity` file.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I just close the database in my code

```
database.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Open Android studio > Go to App Inspection > Database

then, click that **power icon** to and toggle to **yellow lock** that will open Connection and this will work

[image]

*If this solved your issue don't forget to upvote* :) Good day

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to downgrade the three dependencies associated with Room. It was at 2.6.something and then I downgraded to 2.5.2.